# Is this grammar left recursive?

Tags: grammar

I know of two types of left recursion, immediate and indirect, and I don't think the following grammar falls into any of them, but is that the case?

And is this grammar an LL grammar? Why or why not?

```
E ::= T+E | T  
T ::= F*T | F  
F ::= id | (E)
```

Comment: Flag it as homework; show us your work; doesn't belong on SO, has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you start with `E`. Both of `E`’s alternatives start with a `T`. Both of `T`’s  alternatives start with `F`. Both of `F`’s alternatives start with a terminal symbol. Thus, the grammar is not left recursive.